# Mathematical expression of finding minima from a histogram

Tags: functions

How to write a mathematical expression for locating a minima in an accumulative histogram?

[image]

Edit:
In the context of image processing, I want to separate an object from its background where x-axis is the intensity of the pixels, and y-axis is the number of pixels.

Comment: What's the purpose of that red vertical line there? And why does it matter that this is an "accumulative histogram" and not just any function? Your question is seriously lacking context, as well as your own thoughts and efforts on it (so I wouldn't count on others to make that effort for you).

Comment: That looks like a curve rather than a histogram.  If it was a histogram, you might want a point with higher values each side (a strict local minimum).  If it was a well behaved curve, you might want a point with a zero first derivative and positive second derivative.

Comment: @Henry it's a histogram with only one very high peak

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but your problem is that you wish to find local minima of you blue curve, but it is too noisy for doing so, is that right?

Comment: @caverac I would like to know how to address this using mathematical expression

Comment: Unless you have a model for the curve, a closed mathematical expression is impossible

Comment: @caverac I see. How about finding the highest peak (there's only one), then the local minimum after it is the one. But I'm not sure how to write it in equations.

Comment: If you call $y_i$ the array with the histogram, then the maximum is: $${\rm max_j}\{ y_j : y_{j-1} < y_j > y_{j + 1}\}$$. The minimum is a but trickier, but if you know that it is located between $x=m$ and $x  = n$, then $${\rm min_j}\{ y_j : y_{j-1} > y_j < y_{j + 1}~\mbox{and}~m < j < n\}$$

Comment: @caverac got it. now I just need to figure out how to define m, n. Thanks

Comment: Just by looking at the histogram, for you case I guess $m\sim 7000$ and $n\sim 8000$

Comment: @caverac yes, but it might change.

Comment: Try this, $f_h(x) = (f\star G_h) (x)$, where $G$ is a Gaussian filter of width $h$. Then solve the problem $f'_h(x) = 0$ and $f''_h(x) > 0$. "$\star$" is a convolution

Comment: @caverac thanks. please write it as an answer so that I can choose as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define

$$
f_h(x) = (f \star G_h)(x)
$$

where $G_h$ is a [Gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter) of width $h$, and $ f\star g$ means the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of $f$ and $g$. You can then take the derivative of $f_h$ to find its minima

$$
\frac{df_h}{dx} = 0
$$